# failed to deduce unused template argument in variadic-template

Tags: c++, std, variadic-templates

It's obvious that the code below can compile and run.

```cpp
template<typename ...Args>
void func (Args... args) { }

func(1,2,3,4,5); // succeed
```

```cpp
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
void func (T arg_1, Args... args) { }

func(1,2,3,4,5); //succeed
```

But if I seperate one template parameter `T` and don't use it, it won't compile.

```cpp
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
void func (Args... args) { }

func(1,2,3,4,5); // can't compile
```

g++ throws error:

```cpp
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:33:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘func(int, int, int, int, int)’
   33 |  func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
      |                    ^
main.cpp:26:6: note: candidate: ‘template<class T, class ... Args> void func(Args ...)’
   26 | void func (Args... args)
      |      ^~~~
main.cpp:26:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:33:20: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘T’
   33 |  func(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

It can alse compile if specify the first template parameter explicitly when use:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
void func (Args... args) { }
func<int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5); //succeed
```

Why must I specify the parameter explicitly or use it ?

Though nobody will do that, I just wonder how the compiler deduct the parameter.

Comment: It's just like me telling you: *'Please translate this specific comment'* – and omitting the language to which to translate to...

Comment: unrelated to variadic BTW, `template <typename T1, typename T2> void foo(T2);` would have same "issue".

Comment: @Aconcagua It's very figurative. It seems that I thought the compiler too smart.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiating a template requires all of its parameters to be specified or deduced. This is a fundamental rule, there are no exceptions or workarounds.

There plenty of templates that don't use any of their parameters, like. `std::integer_sequence`. Template parameters serve a purpose even if they are not referenced in the template itself.